# Form values showing up as null on JSP

Tags: javascript, html, forms, jsp, input

When I submit input values through from and try to access it in the server side,
every value appears to be null. Although, when I check the network requests, the values are appended on to them correctly. its only when it reaches the server side jsp code that it appears to be null.

Here is the form from the html side:

```
<form name="modifyUser" action="/UserController/modifyUser" method="post" >
            <label for="userName">User Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" value="test1">    <br> 

        <label for="fName">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="fName" id="fName" value="test1"><br>

        <label for="lName">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="lName" id="lName" value="test1"><br>

        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="test@test.net"><br>

        <label for="nPass">New Password</label>
        <input type="text" name="nPass" id="nPass"><br>

        <label for="cPass">Confirm Password</label>
        <input type="text" name="cPass" id="cPass"><br>

        <div id="warning" class="feedback"></div>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" id="submit"/>

        <input type="hidden" name="userID" id="userID" value="1">
    </fieldset>

    <br/>
</form>
```

Here is the code snippet from the server side:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    if(requestURI.endsWith("modifyUser")){
        user.setEmail((String)request.getParameter("mail"));
        user.setUserName((String)request.getParameter("name"));
        user.setfName((String)request.getParameter("fmail"));
        user.setlName((String)request.getParameter("lmail"));
        String cPass = (String)request.getParameter("cPass");
        String nPass = (String)request.getParameter("nPass");
    }
}
```

Comment: Except `nPass` and `cPass`  all names looks different from jsp form

Comment: omg.. I was given with code from my team members.. just noticed it.. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since we do not have values with such id (mail/name/fmail/lmail) in the request param we are getting NULL value (*the **value for an id passed** from jsp in request **does not matches with the value obtained**)*  from server side.

Please try with the following server side code.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
if(requestURI.endsWith("modifyUser")){
    user.setEmail((String)request.getParameter("email"));
    user.setUserName((String)request.getParameter("userName"));
    user.setfName((String)request.getParameter("fName"));
    user.setlName((String)request.getParameter("lName"));
    String cPass = (String)request.getParameter("cPass");
    String nPass = (String)request.getParameter("nPass");
}
```

}